# How to get output table from input table using mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Input Table:

```
Visitor   Page Visited       TimeStamp
A            P1               6:41:21
A            P1               6:41:35
A            P2               6:42:54
A            P2               6:43:53
A            P1               6:44:09
A            P1               6:44:54
```

I have to find journey of the visitor (In this case a visitor 'A' is going to page P1 then P2 then again back to P1) at page level with its start time stamp(on that page) and end time stamp(on that page)

Each row is a particular activity a visitor does on a page which is recorded as a hit so each row represents a hit with time stamp.

Output table should look like:

```
Visitor   Page Visited       StartTime   EndTime
A            P1               6:41:21    6:41:35        
A            P2               6:42:54    6:43:53
A            P1               6:44:09    6:44:54
```

Comment: Is there any primary key defined for this table

Comment: Hi. Please read [ask] & hits from googling 'stackexchange homework', also the edit box help. We are not here to do your homework. Also "journey of the visitor at visit page level" is not clear, please edit your question to be clear. Don't cram a few words into a sentence.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Constraints including PKs & FKs are neither necessary nor sufficient to query. One needs to know why/when/what rows go into tables. Constraints just help you guess. As long as you are asking, ask what the tables mean.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Actually there are 4 columns in table which uniquely identify a visitor on a webpage, so you can assume visitor ID (A in this case) to be your primary key.  I will surely take your suggestions on my questions posting skills as I am new to this platform. Thansk

Comment: Please refrain yourself from posting unnecessary comments. Only in case you know the solution or need some clarifications do comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would be easier.

```
SELECT Visitor, pageVisited as 'Page Visited', min(timestampTemp) StartTime, 
max(timestampTemp) EndTime from 
(select @pvt:= @pvt+(@pv!=a.pageVisited) pvt,@pv:=a.pageVisited,a.* from 
(select @pv:='', @pvt:=0) vars, testTab a order by visitor,timestampTemp) t
group by t.pvt, t.visitor;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0cca99/1/0

Comment: @Puneet I see you accepted this. Do try this with a dataset with multiple visitors (the sample you provided here has only one visitor). I am not sure if it works in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. I used [this](https://explainextended.com/2009/07/24/mysql-grouping-continuous-ranges/) awesome blog post to build the query.

Basically, it uses MySQL user-defined variables to keep track of state change (where "state" I took as combination of visitor + page), while ordering the entire table by timestamp and then by page and visitor (i.e. state). The counter `gn` increments by one whenever the state changes. The outer query then simply picks the min and max of the timestamp as begin and end, while grouping by `gn`.

My table with test data is called `dummy` and the columns corresponding to your source table are `visitor, pg, visited`. For simplicity, I used `char` datatype for all 3 columns, converting timestamp column to time when ordering etc. You may store it as `datetime` type which will remove the need for conversion.

For future reference, this is also known as the "islands problem". You can google this to find more solutions using other methods.

```
SELECT  visitor AS Visitor, pg as 'Page Visited', MIN(visited) AS StartTime, max(visited) as EndTime
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := @r + (@state != concat(visitor,concat('->',pg)) OR @state IS NULL) AS gn,
                @state := concat(visitor,concat('->',pg)) AS sn,
                s.visitor, convert(s.visited, TIME) as visited, s.pg
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @r := 0,
                        @state := NULL
                ) vars,
                dummy s
        ORDER BY
                convert(visited, TIME), pg, visitor
        ) q
group by gn, pg, visitor
```

SQL fiddle where you can check my source data and query output : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b41758/4/0